# Drag and Drop at the frontend does not save new order

Tags: component, custom-component, ajax, sorting

In my Joomla3.6 component, I am trying to implement drag and drop ordering at the frontend. I followed [Adding drag-n-drop ordering in component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/14374/12352) and I can move the list-items, but it never saves the new order.

I tried to overwrite `saveOrderAjax()` at the controller, but it seems that it is not even called.

Any idea? Does anybody know a component with frontend-ordering?

Comment: check if your front-end component view table has `ordering` field in it's table.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for that comment, @Liz, that pointed me to the solution. I already had the `ordering` field, but now I found out that it only works, if the controller of the list-view points to the model for the form-view:

```
class MyCompControllerOrderings extends JControllerAdmin
{
    public function getModel($name = 'MyModelForTheTable', $prefix = 'MyCompModel', $config = array('ignore_request' => true)) {
        $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);
        return $model;
    }
}
```

And this model only works, if it defines `public function getTable` and `public function getForm`.

It seems not to be enough to define the `getTable` method, but why?

Anyhow, now it works.